# CakePHP 2 - Why am i getting sql error in model function?

Tags: sql, cakephp, model, cakephp-2.0

I am trying to do the simplest call through my controller and model, but it doesn't work.

The error I get is:

> Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You
>   have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
>   'ppLongerFunction2' at line 1

The controller code is:

```
<?php

class UsersController extends AppController{
public $uses = array('User');

function test(){
    $blah = $this->User->find('all');
    $u = $this->User->ppLongerFunction2();
    $this->set(compact('blah', 'u'));
}
}
```

And the Model is:

```
<?php
class User extends AppModel{
public var $name = 'User';
var $displayField = 'username';

var $useTable = 'users';

public function ppLongerFunction2(){
    $something = $this->find('all');
    return $something;
}
}
```

Where am I messing up?

Stack Trace:

```
#0 C:\wamp\www\lib\Cake\Model\Datasource\DboSource.php(436): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 C:\wamp\www\lib\Cake\Model\Datasource\DboSource.php(403): DboSource->_execute('ppLongerFunctio...', Array)
#2 C:\wamp\www\lib\Cake\Model\Datasource\DboSource.php(647): DboSource->execute('ppLongerFunctio...', Array, Array)
#3 C:\wamp\www\lib\Cake\Model\Datasource\DboSource.php(589): DboSource->fetchAll('ppLongerFunctio...', Array, Array)
#4 C:\wamp\www\lib\Cake\Model\Model.php(720): DboSource->query('ppLongerFunctio...', Array, Object(AppModel))
#5 C:\wamp\www\app\Controller\UsersController.php(11): Model->__call('ppLongerFunctio...', Array)
#6 C:\wamp\www\app\Controller\UsersController.php(11): AppModel->ppLongerFunction2()
#7 [internal function]: UsersController->test()
#8 C:\wamp\www\lib\Cake\Controller\Controller.php(473): ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(Object(UsersController), Array)
#9 C:\wamp\www\lib\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php(104): Controller->invokeAction(Object(CakeRequest))
#10 C:\wamp\www\lib\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php(86): Dispatcher->_invoke(Object(UsersController), Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#11 C:\wamp\www\app\webroot\index.php(96): Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#12 {main}
```

---

All fixed. It was a file-name. Thanks for the help :| stupid

Comment: What's the SQL query it's creating?  (If you haven't yet installed DebugKit, it's a MUST for any CakePHP project and can give you all this information easily - variables, mysql queryies run...etc etc)

Comment: ALso, probably not the main issue, but you don't need $uses for User since you're IN the UsersController.

Comment: I don't have debutKit, another way, i can show you the query?

Comment: You really should get DebugKit - 100% positive you won't regret it.  To display your recent SQL queries in the view, use this:  `<?php echo $this->element('sql_dump'); ?>`.  (make sure Debug is set to 2 in your  `Config/core.php` file.)

Comment: I did install it but it doesn't seem to work with CakePHP 2 :(. What I discovered is that the function in the model does not get called at all. I put a `die('here')` and it doesn't die. The Controller can't find the model function...

Comment: Try getting rid of `var` - just `public $name = ...`  (Just FYI DebugKit most certainly works with Cake 2 - I'm using 2.0 and 2.1 on different projects, and it works on both - just make sure you're downloading the correct version)

Comment: Also, you don't need the $useTable line at all - 'users' is the default for a "User" model already.

Answer (score 0):

What seems to be happening is that your controller tries to call the model's `ppLongerFunction2()` but it isn't defined in the model and therefor it is passed as an SQL function.

What I believe happens is that you've someplace missed following conventions and the file for the Model (`User.php`) can't be found (perhaps it is `user.php`). In this case cake will build the model from the DB table internally and it will obviously won't include the function. You can check if this is the case by typing something bogus in your model that would definitely cause an error, like a missing `;` and see if the error comes up. If it doesn't your file isn't used.